# Sitecore 10.2 Integration with Azure B2C using Owin Middleware

Tags: sso, azure-b2c

I am using an ASP.NET MVC application to connect to AD using owin middleware. This is the startup class:

```
try {
IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions{});
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions 
{
                                           Authority = Globals.Authority, 
                                           ClientId = Globals.ClientId,
                                           RedirectUri = Globals.RedirectUri,
                                           PostLogoutRedirectUri = Globals.RedirectUri,
                                           Scope = Globals.BasicSignInScopes,  // a basic set of permissions for user
                                                                              // sign in & profile access
                                           TokenValidationParameters =
                                               new TokenValidationParameters
                                                   {
                                                       // In a real application you would use ValidateIssuer = true for
                                                       // additional checks and security.
                                                       NameClaimType = "email", 
                                                       SaveSigninToken = false,
                                                       ValidateIssuer = false
                                                   },
                                           Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                                               {
                                                   SecurityTokenValidated = OnSecurityTokenValidated,
                                                   AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                                                   AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                                               },
                                           ResponseType = "id_token",
                                           ProtocolValidator = new OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator()
                                               { 
                                                   RequireStateValidation = false,
                                                   RequireNonce = true},
                                                   CookieManager = new SameSiteCookieManager(new SystemWebCookieManager())
                                               });} catch (Exception ex) {
Log.Error("OwinMiddleWareIntialize Error", ex.Message);}
```

OnSecurityTokenValidate Method:

```
private Task OnSecurityTokenValidated(SecurityTokenValidatedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
    {
        Log.Info("Line:121 OwinMiddleWare.OnSecurityTokenValidated", this);
        Log.Info("NameClaimType" + Globals.NameClaimType, this);
        Log.Info("PVGroupsAD" + Globals.PVGroupsAD, this);
        var protectedState = notification.ProtocolMessage.State.Split('=')[1];
        Log.Info("127:protectedState" + protectedState, this);
        var state = notification.Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(protectedState);
        Log.Info("state" + state, this);
        //get idtoken in notification.protocol
        var Idtoken = notification.ProtocolMessage.IdToken;
        Log.Info("Idtoken" + Idtoken, this);
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        Log.Info("Line:133 handler" + handler, this);
        var jsonToken = handler.ReadToken(Idtoken);
        Log.Info("135:jsonToken" + jsonToken, this);
        var tokenS = jsonToken as JwtSecurityToken;
        Log.Info("Line:136 tokenS" + tokenS, this);
        var tokenExp = tokenS.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type.Equals("exp")).Value;
        Log.Info("Line:138 tokenExp" + tokenExp, this);
        //DateTime owin_valid_date;
        //DateTime.TryParseExact(tokenExp, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out owin_valid_date);
        //Log.Info("Line:141 owin_valid_date" + owin_valid_date, this);
        var ticks = long.Parse(tokenExp);
        Log.Info("Line:143 ticks" + ticks, this);
        DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        Log.Info("Line:145 origin" + origin, this);
        var expiryTime = origin.AddSeconds(ticks);
        Log.Info("Line:147 expiryTime" + expiryTime, this);
        var now = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
        Log.Info("Line:149 now" + now, this);
        var valid = expiryTime >= now;
        Log.Info("Line:151 valid" + valid, this);
        Log.Info("Line:152 IDToken" + Idtoken.ToString(), this);
        var jti = tokenS.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == Globals.NameClaimType).Value;
        Log.Info("Line:154 jti" + jti, this);
        //var jti1 = tokenS.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == Globals.PVGroupsAD).Value;
        //Log.Info("Line:156 jti1" + jti1, this);
        if (!valid)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["internalUserToken"] = "1";
            Log.Info("10Owin-internalUserToken" + HttpContext.Current.Session["internalUserToken"], this);
        }
        if (!Globals.NameClaimType.Equals("name") && Globals.PVGroupsAD.Contains(jti))
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["internalUserToken"] = Idtoken.ToString();
            Log.Info("11Owin-internalUserToken" + HttpContext.Current.Session["internalUserToken"], this);
        }
        else
        if (!Globals.NameClaimType.Equals("name"))
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["internalUserToken"] = "1";
            Log.Info("12Owin-internalUserToken" + HttpContext.Current.Session["internalUserToken"], this);
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["internalUserToken"] = Idtoken.ToString();
            Log.Info("13Owin-internalUserToken" + HttpContext.Current.Session["internalUserToken"], this);
        }
        Log.Info("Line:178 OnSecurityTokenValidate.InternalToken" + HttpContext.Current.Session["internalUserToken"]?.ToString(), this);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

We are not seeing OnSecurityToken Method is getting called every time. Due to this we are having inconsistent issue in our site.

We are using .NET Framework 4.8.

We are not getting redirected to the redirect URI which is mentioned in the AD, the screen is getting redirected to homepage.

Any suggestion might help here thanks in advance

We are trying to authenticate AD login with Sitecore 10.2 docker using OwinMiddleware